# FieldAttribute Group property does not work for collections

Tags: codeeffects

The `FieldAttribute.Group` property does not work when applied to a collection.  In the example below, on the rules editor I get two menu items (group, OTHER). Under the `group` menu item I get `MyField` and under `OTHER` I get `MyCollection` and `OtherField`.  I expect that `group` to have `MyField` and `MyCollection`.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    [Field(Settable = false, Group = "group")]
    public int MyField { get; set; }

    [Field(Settable = false, Group = "group")]
    public List<int> MyCollection { get; set; }

    [Field(Settable = false)]
    public int OtherField { get; set; }
}

// here is how the editor is instantiated
RuleEditor editor = new RuleEditor("divRuleEditor")
{
   Mode = Common.RuleType.Execution,
   SourceType = typeof(MyModel)
};
```

[image]

Comment: Which platform/source type do you use?

Comment: ASP.NET Core version 3.1

Comment: I added a code snippet to the question showing the editor instantiation.

Comment: @Alex any update on this issue?

Comment: This issue will be fixed in the next minor version of the editor. I can't tell when exactly it's going to be released. A couple of weeks, possibly

Comment: This bug was fixed in the latest version